# Font-size differences in input fields on FF 3.5 for Mac?

Tags: html, css, firefox, rendering, font-size

I've noticed while testing my website that the font-size in  fields on FF 3.5 on Mac's is bigger than on FF 3.5 for windows or any other browser.

Is there a way to style this or fix it?  I've tried setting input { font-size: XXpx; } to no avail!

Comment: Can you post a link to your site?

Comment: Bigger in what way, in width, in height or in weight? Fixed-width or variable? Font available on both systems? Note that Arial and Helvetica are close, but not equal fonts, so even if you use pixels for sizes everywhere, you may still find differences.

Comment: @Walker: you missed the "deadline" of the bounty. Just curious, have you had a look at my answer and does it help in any way?

Comment: @Abel, thanks for the reply - I'm still having some trouble but I appreciate the input.

Comment: Good to see you back, pity you lost your bounty... What are the issues you still have or that are still unclear? (may be posted under my answer, if related)

Comment: @Abel, Yeah I'm sorry about that, really busy schedule here.  For some reason on one of our developers macs (the rest of use linux or windows) the text side in inputs is much larger than on the rest of our computers (FF 3.5).  It's really confusing and frustrating because we use autoclear on several inputs and this makes obscures some of the text.

Comment: Well, as you might've understood from my text, this behavior is as expected. If my post (or the others) don't help solving it, then please give a link to your site, or make a dummy page that illustrates your issue. Maybe we can help you further.

Comment: Sure - let me investigate a little further and read a little closer and I'll get back to you! Thanks Abel.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### The reason of font size differences

The difference in font-sizes between a Mac-OS and Windows-OS are not necessarily the result of different fonts, because it will also happen when you use equal fonts and sizes. Instead, the reason is historically (see this [background article](http://www.scantips.com/no72dpib.html)): Windows renders text with 96 DPI and the MacOS uses 72 DPI. Occasionally, you may see even different DPI values, for instance when you select Large Fonts in the Windows Display properties (this increases the DPI).

### Confusion and physics

There's a lot of confusion about this. Surely, a pixel is a pixel, so how can one screen have 72 dots per inch with MacOS and that same screen 96 dots per inch with Windows? Well, it cannot. The inches meant here are not real inches. They are logical inches. 72 DPI means: 72 pixels on your current screen (and each screen differs!) we consider as if it were one inch. This is by no means equal to an inch on paper, i.e. 2.54cm, in the physical world.

### Back to web pages and your issue

How does all this relate to your issue? Because I assume that you use points (good!) for your sizes. And one point is defined as 1/72 inch (72 points go in one inch). Now that you know that inches on screens are not inches in real, and that each OS puts a different default dots in each logical inch, you also know that points (or `mm`, `in` or `pc`) are different per system.

### Towards a (not perfect) solution

But, you may ask, if everything is equally, proportionally resized, all should be fine and dandy, relatively speaking? No, not quite. If you use images or if you use pixels for sizes in other elements, this will not work. Pixels are the only absolute logical size that is available to you (even it may come as no surprise that this is by no means an exact size: a pixel's size differs per monitor). If you specify pixels, you surpass the DPI or PPI limitations superimposed by the OS (another [historical note](http://marc.info/?l=mozilla-layout&m=93319001930824&w=2)). I.e.:

```
/* 
   different font-size per OS / DPI display 
   setting compared to input box 
*/
input.text {
    width: 120px;
    font-size: 10pt;
}

/* 
   equal font-size per OS / DPI display 
   setting compared to input box 
*/
input.text {
    width: 120px;
    font-size: 12px;   /* typically, pixels are slightly smaller than points */
}
```

However, even in the above scenario, rendering issues may get back at you. Local stylesheets, available fonts, resizing of viewports and anti-aliasing may add to subtle differences still. But this is the closest you can get to defying the OS-dependent rules.

One subtlety: once you start using pixels, it may become easier to measure your font compared to your images, but you will loose the possibility of scaling your whole design and you'll be stuck with specifying exact sizes everywhere. So whether this is a good idea in your situation is up to you (common practice is to stick with points and leave the rendering up to the browsers and OS to give the users an experience of what they're used to on their system).

### Helvetica vs Arial solution

It has been suggested on this thread that Helvetica is the rendered font on MacOS and the cause of the differences. To be certain, have a look at this page for [spotting Helvetical vs Arial](http://www.ms-studio.com/articlesarialsid.html) in a rendered page. If you use the following CSS, your page will render differently on Windows (Arial) than on MacOS (Helvetica):

```
input.text {
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

But if you use the following code, it will look equal on Windows (Arial) and MacOS ([also Arial](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1642)). Only Linux will look differently still, unless [Windows fonts have been installed](http://linuxhelp.blogspot.com/2005/12/adding-windows-fonts-in-linux.html).

```
input.text {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
```

### Odd little bug with monospace may add to the confusion

If you use monospaced fonts, and even if you specify the font itself, you may end up having differences in rendering still. There's a well-hidden bug in Firefox, but also on some other browsers, that [I reported a while ago](http://web.archive.org/web/20091029094650/http://www.undermyhat.org/blog/2009/09/css-font-family-monospace-renders-inconsistently-in-firefox-and-chrome/) (blog post explains solutions), but hasn't caught much attention.

The simple solution is to specify Courier New always, even when you don't care about the font. I don't think this was the issue in your case, as you mentioned Arial and Helvetica.

### Final thoughts

Why all this hassle, why not one standard? Read this [excellent background article](https://web.archive.org/web/20160301175709/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/fontblog/archive/2005/11/08/490490.aspx) on why Windows thought it was better to increase the DPI with 30%.

Further reading: there's a [whole site dedicated to DPI issues](http://www.emdpi.com/).

Answer (score 2):

I guess the monospace font used in each OS isn't the same. If I remember well, Monaco on Mac OS X and Courier New on Windows XP.

Users are accustomed to the monospace font used on the OS they use, they don't necessarily appreciate another one (or care btw). Do you need to have uniform style across OSes and strictly enforce it?
FYI you're the only one to see a difference between the browsers you mentioned, because you test your site on many browsers (that's a good thing!).
The immense majority of the users will visit your site with only one browser on one OS and won't spot the difference and the 1% that will notice the difference won't care, except if it's twice the size somewhere or affect the readibility of the informations displayed.

To style these texts, you can use font-family (see the fonts declared here on SO with Firebug or Web Developer Toolbar (Ctrl-Shift-F), it seems well thought to me), [font-stretch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/font-stretch) and [font-size-adjust](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/font-size-adjust)
AFAIK font-stretch isn't implemented anywhere

Font support by browsers still need a LOT of improvements, you can't fine tune them like in Photoshop.

Comment: Sure, thanks for all the great advice!  Here's my problem:  The fonts on Mac are about 2px bigger than the fonts on windows, and I use Autoclear (I have text in input fields that describes the field or gives an example and disappears on click).  What happens is sometimes the explanations or descriptions are fine in all windows/linux browsers but are too big on a Mac.

I do set font-family and font-size - but it seems Helvetica (mac) is bigger than Arial (windows) or there is some strange behavior going on.

Answer (score 2):

Felipe is right: every OS/Browser combination has a different starting point regarding to font sizes and some other elements.

Try applying a **CSS reset** to your website before anything, and start building from there. Maybe it helps.
http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/3/cssreset/

Comment: Agreed. Use a global reset to redefine the starting font-size. Then scale your fonts with EM units instead of PX

Comment: Resetting the CSS does not by itself change the difference in rendering of fonts, which simply *is* different per OS.

Answer (score 0):

Try forcing the font to arial, as it is included in all operating systems, and it looks good to.

Comment: Arial is not readily available on most Linux systems, you have to install them manually with something like `sudo apt-get install msttcorefonts`.